# How can I use fixup_bundle to add libraries to a framework on OSX?

Tags: macos, cmake, frameworks, rpath

I've used CMake to create a framework on OSX, but the framework dynamically links with libusb. How can I use `fixup_bundle()` or something else to copy `libusb.dylib` into the framework bundle, and fix my library's `rpath` so it points into the framework, instead of the absolute path of the `libusb` I built?

Answer (score 0):

Fixing the `rpath` turned out to be relatively easy:

```
set_target_properties(mylib PROPERTIES
    # Build a framework on OSX.
    FRAMEWORK TRUE
    # Add a relative path for dependencies to the rpath of mylib (when installed).
    INSTALL_RPATH "@loader_path"
    # But also use the INSTALL_RPATH anyway in the build tree, before it is installed.
    BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH TRUE
)
```

But that doesn't copy the dependencies into the framework. I do that manually:

```
# Copy libfoo into the bundle.
if (APPLE)
    add_custom_command(TARGET mylib POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy "$<TARGET_FILE:libfoo>" "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:mylib>"
        COMMENT "Bundling libfoo"
        VERBATIM
    )
endif ()
```